# ErrorType - iOS9 only?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, swift2, ios9

According to Xcode's documentation ErrorType is available for iOS 9 and above.
I tried to work with it on iOS 8.3 simulator and it's working great.
Is this a documentation error? Or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ErrorType` is not related to iOS, it's a [feature](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) of Swift 2.

Wherever you can use Swift 2, you can use ErrorType.

The Xcode popup is indeed ambiguous about this.